# How to use Cosmos DB trigger to merge document

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a project that using Azure Stream Analytics to save messages from an event hub to the Cosmos DB.
But since Cosmos upsert overwrite the existing document, and I dont want to lose any existing data elements.
The idea here is to use the Cosmos DB pre-trigger that find the current data with same id and merge to the new document before saving it. The trigger looks like this:

```
function mergeData(){
        var context = getContext();
    var collection = context.getCollection();
    var container = context.getCollection();
    var request = context.getRequest();

    // item to be created
    var newItem = request.getBody();
    
        // query for latest existing records
    var filterQuery = "SELECT * FROM root c where c.id=\"" + newItem.id + "\" order by c._ts desc";
        
        var accept = container.queryDocuments(container.getSelfLink(), filterQuery,
            queryOldRecords);
    if (!accept) throw "Unable to query for older documents, abort";

        function queryOldRecords(err, items, responseOptions) {       
        if (err) throw new Error("Error" + err.message);

        if (items.length > 0) {
            // merge logic here
                        newItem.name = items[0].name;
                        request.setBody(newItem);
                }
    }
}
```

The trigger is set as pre and for replace with the Cosmos DB container.

However the trigger does not work, I keep seeing ASA upsert overwrite the document and lost previous data.
(Have not tested with code to direct insert records to Cosmos DB.)
Here are the questions:

1. Will the trigger be automatically executed when the ASA upsert occurred?
2. If not do I need to code in the ASA to include the trigger to be executed and how?
3. How to debug the Cosmos DB trigger in general and specially in this case?
4. Is there other way to achieve this?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Just found out "Triggers are not automatically triggered. Rather, you have to explicitly specify the trigger in the operation that you want to activate the trigger. " So question is how to make ASA include the trigger?

Comment: Also "There is no trigger in ASA for CosmosDb.", so this solution is not feasible at all.

Comment: fyi this is off-topic as written, as you're asking multiple questions, each either a yes/no or a fairly broad topic, ending in a very broad "is there another way to achieve this?" This is simply too broad.

Comment: Also: Stream Analytics directly supports upserts; it's unclear why you require use of a trigger.

Comment: If you're trying to add/update existing properties to an existing document you will need to merge it yourself. Normally this would mean manually iterating through every object and array. But you might want to look into Partial Document Updates. https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update

Comment: First time post a question here, sorry if caused any confusing.
The ASA does support the upsert, but it overwrite the old document, if the new document does not contains some elements then they are gone after the upsert, that is why I want to apply merge instead.
Thanks for the partial document update link, very interesting, will try it.

Answer (score 0):

From this link: [ASA documentdb output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-documentdb-output)

> With compatibility level 1.0, Stream Analytics performs this update as a PATCH operation, so it enables partial updates to the document. Stream Analytics adds new properties or replaces an existing property incrementally. However, changes in the values of array properties in your JSON document result in overwriting the entire array. That is, the array isn't merged.
> With 1.2, upsert behavior is modified to insert or replace the document.

I switched ASA to level 1.0, it does not even connect to Cosmos DB.
But with level 1.1, the update is working as PATCH operations which the json element not be removed if not presenting in the new document, and updated if value is different.
The level 1.2 (as default) is just doing the upsert without PATCH operation.